# XAMPP Delay in localhost

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I am currently designing my own website, and I am using XAMPP for hosting.

I modified the CSS, HTML files and replaced the picture with new one in the folder. But when I open the web page in localhost, the pictures are not updated. I restarted and re-installed XAMPP and still can't get the new pictures display in the web page.

Also, when I modified the CSS and HTML files, I often have to wait for a long time before I can see the changes in localhost.

What is the causing the delay? And how can I speed things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser may be caching the files. Try doing a hard reload with CTRL+R or SHIFT+F5

Comment: just what i was about to post. also see the information on this [page](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/)

Comment: Now, in google chrome, just pressing ctrl+R or shift+f5 doesn't clear the cache. Hold the mouse at reload button and select the third option - "clear cache and do hard reset".